# how to remove middle characters in a string in python

Tags: python

I really do not know how to figure it out!!!

```
 remove_middle_character("apple")
'aple'
 remove_middle_character("banana")
'bana'
 remove_middle_character("discount")
‘disunt‘
”“”
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please post what you've tried so far. We'll be happy to help you figure out a problem, but the point isn't for other people to write all your code for you ; ). Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers.

Comment: You might like to pluralise the function name, i.e. `remove_middle_characters()` because 2 characters can be removed for even length strings, e.g. `discount -> disunt`

Answer (score 3):

Since it's probably classwork, I'm not going to give you the code (which you would be unwise using anyway since your educational institution probably knows about Stack Overflow and would catch you out with plagiarism). Instead, I'll provide guidance on what you need to know.

If the string or of size two or less (we handle this early so that we don't have to worry about edge cases in the following steps), just return an empty string.

Otherwise, if the length of the string is odd, get the length `x`, and return the first `x // 2` (the `//` operator is integer division) characters concatenated with the character starting at `x // 2 + 1`.

Otherwise, return the first `x // 2 - 1` characters concatenated with the characters starting at `x // 2 + 1`.

In terms of turning that into code:

- you can get the length of a string `x` with `len(x)`;
- you can get the first `n` characters with `x[:n]`;
- you can get the characters starting at `m` with `x[m:]`;
- you can concatenate strings with `+`; and
- you can test if a value `p` is even by using `if (p % 2) == 0` (and, of course, odd numbers will cause `(p % 2) == 1` to evaluate as true).

That should be *all* you need to write the code yourself.

Comment: Although the function name suggests removal of a single character, the examples show the middle 2 characters are to be removed for even length strings, so a string of length two should also return an empty string. Otherwise this is good advice without handing it all out on a platter.

Comment: Good point, @mhawke, the title (and the examples) indicate the true nature of the question - I have adjusted the answer accordingly: return empty string for length zero, one *and two.*

Answer (score -1):

Using all the excellent suggestions above, I suggest a refactored approach where the edge conditions mentioned by paxdiablo and enhanced by mhawke are catered for but remove the need for using an if-else statement.

As you can see from paxdiablo if the string length is odd (the modulo function returns 1) the fist part of the string is:
x // 2 (subtract 0).
If the string length is even (the modulo function returns 0) the fist part of the string is:
x // 2 - 1 (subtract 1).

In both cases (odd and even length), the second part of the string is:
x // 2 + 1

So we need to subtract the reverse of what the modulo 2 of the string length would give us.  We can do this by making an even length odd and an odd length even. One possible way is: mod = (len(s) + 1) % 2.  So a possible solution might look like:

```
def remove_middle_character(s):
    h = len(s)//2
    mod = (len(s) + 1) % 2
    return s[:h - mod] + s[h + 1:]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(remove_middle_character(""))
    print(remove_middle_character("x"))
    print(remove_middle_character("xy"))
    print(remove_middle_character("apple"))
    print(remove_middle_character("banana"))
    print(remove_middle_character("discount"))
```

Comment: There is a reason why other suggestions didn't give out code. Please remove this code part, if possible.

Comment: Thank you so much，I also tried this way. it's working.                 new_string1=""
      new_string2=""
      for char in s:
            if len(s)%2==0:
                  new_string1 = s[:len(s)/2-1]
                  new_string2 = s[len(s)/2+1:]
                  
            else:
                  new_string1 = s[:(len(s)+1)/2-1]
                  new_string2 = s[len(s)/2+1:]

      return new_string1+new_string2